# Xcode 9.3 - terrible performance

Tags: xcode, performance, xcode9.3

**ENVIRONMENT**

MBP (mid 2015) 16GB i7

**PROBLEM**

After updating Xcode to 9.3, Xcode becomes very very slow and always in high (**400%**) CPU usage which makes everything get stuck. Just look at those screenshots.

**WHEN USING XCODE**

[image: high CPU usage]

[image: high CPU usage - Xcode consumes more than 400%]

**After quitting Xcode:**

[image: low CPU usage after quitting Xcode]

Auto-complete and breakpoint just can't be used. I need to wait tens of seconds until Xcode has a response. It's not endurable.

Relaunch and reboot doesn't work. And before Xcode 9.3, these issues existed but didn't appear so often.

Comment: Did you try to delete Derived Data? How much free space do you have on your drive?

Comment: @the4kman Thank you for your response. It doesn't work. It may solve the issue temporarily, but it will appear when I keep using Xcode. More than 30G.

Comment: @Tepmnthar Maybe your project is too big and scv is attached to xcode, scv can slow 
down.

Comment: @AlexeyUsachov what is scv?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Or SVC - system version control, like git, svn, mercurial.

Comment: Yes, the project is a bit large and uses git. But it used to work. The only difference is that I started using private pods to split different modules in the project. Does that matters?